# environments fail to align with surroundings

Tags: vertical-alignment, environments

In the following examples, neither the alignment parameter `t` nor `b` works(please see the attached figure). Why and how to make environment align with its surroundings.

**Codes:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newbox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\parbox{3in}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item 1\item 2\item 3\item 4\item 5
  \end{itemize} 
}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Exp 1. Aligned by t:\par
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
  \begin{lstlisting}[]
      ab
      cd
      ef
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\vrule\ 
\parbox[t]{3in}{\usebox\mybox}
\par\bigskip
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Exp 2. Aligned by b:\par
\begin{minipage}[b]{2in}
    \begin{lstlisting}[]
      ab
      cd
      ef
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
\vrule\ 
\parbox[b]{3in}{\usebox\mybox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \usebox\mybox makes a 1-line paragraph so [t] and [b]   on the surrounding parbox are the same thing

Comment: I guess adjustbox can be used.

Comment: The alignment of the saved box matters. Currently its reference point is in the middle. Try `xxxx\usebox\mybox` to see where is reference point is, and compare this with the result if you use [t] when saving (`\savebox\mybox{\parbox[t]{3in}` )

Comment: @user202729 or `\raisebox`, but neither can really work unless you assume you already know the alignment points. Answer is probably not to use the outer parbox and use the correct alignment on the inner one. Or an l3 coffin is designed for exactly this use, recording muliple aligment points in a box.